# DOM NamedNodeMap.removeNamedItem() does not work for 'style' attribute in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, dom, microsoft-edge

I ran into a strange bug (feature?) of `NamedNodeMap.removeNamedItem()` running in Microsoft Edge:

I can use `removeNamedItem()` to remove most element attributes, but it does not remove the `style` attribute.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="some classes" style="font-weight:bold;">test div</div>
```

This JavaScript code removes the `class` attribute, but not the `style` attribute:

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');

div.attributes.removeNamedItem('class');  ← works
div.attributes.removeNamedItem('style');  ← doesn't work
```

To reproduce: https://jsbin.com/pijecihomo/1/edit?html,js,output

Is this a known limitation documented somewhere? Are there any other "special" attributes that cannot be removed?

Comment: As I remember, I have an issue with `style` attribute in IE. If you set it by node.setAttribute('style', 'width: 10px') it will not apply styles to ie (can't remember version), hovewer, it will apply styles to selected node in other browsers. So, most probably, it is not a bug, it is MS feature.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

In your question I read that you don't really ask for a solution, but perhaps for others who follow Google and stubble upon this...

```
    node.attributes.removeNamedItem('style');
    if (node.attributes.getNamedItem('style') != null)
      node.attributes.getNamedItem('style').value = '';
```

This ofcourse will not remove the attribute, but at least the CSS inside is removed.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: no Edge a hand to repro, but does this mean even `Element.removeAttribute` fails to remove it?

Comment: @Kaiido Indeed. It simply doesn't remove it, but with that... it also doesn't throw any exception... :(